How to serve static files for django-cms on DigitalOcean?
I have deployed a django-cms app on DigitalOcean following the steps in this tutorial:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-django-to-app-platform
The app is up and running, but static-files are not served.
I created the additional static site referring to the same GitHub repository, and it is up and running too.
settings.py
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "staticfiles")

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    BASE_DIR / "project_name" / "static",
]

I did collect the static files with python manage.py collectstatic and the folder and files are present in the intended location.
How do I "connect" the app on DigitalOcean to my static files?
Some screenshots from DigitalOcean:




Ensure you have added two separate services in DigitalOcean. One service should be used to serve the HTTP requests at the root URL / using Python. The other service should be used to serve the /static URL from the staticfiles directory as the output directory.

That´s what I did. But how does the first know from the second? The do have different names (dolphin-app, monkfish-app)

Solution using Whitenoise:
https://whitenoise.readthedocs.io/en/stable/django.html
Change settings.py
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'whitenoise.runserver_nostatic', # Above 'django.contrib.staticfiles'
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.sites',
     ...
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware', # Here
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    ...
]

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "staticfiles")

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    BASE_DIR / "project_name" / "static",
]

# Whitenoise
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'

and run python manage.py collectstatic on the server.
This might not be the solution to the question but works like a charme!
